# How to make transparent NestedScrollView when adding layout_behavior

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I want to make `NestedScrollView` transparent, but when I use  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` then it add white background. When I remove `layout_behavior`, my design is broken but it shows as transparent background and shows `NestedScrollView` inside top of the view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/android_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroidExample"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/parallax_header_imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/greeting_card3"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/android_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_parallax_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:verticalSpacing="16dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this same problem when I realized the problem.

If you set transparent background to `NestedScrollView` it will be transparent. You will see the activity/fragment background color, but you will not see your image background from `AppBarLayout`. And this is not a bug, the thing is your `AppBarLayout` is collapsing, althougth you set a parallax multiplier of 1, the view collapse and the `NestedScrollView` fills all the screen.

So, what can you do? It's easy! You just have to set your image outside and let the `AppBarLayout` as a placeholder to see the image while it's not collapsed.

This works pretty well when using `app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"` because setting the image outside `AppBarLayout` implies losing the parallax effect for the image.